# What happens on the server when a MySQL client connection is lost?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, connectivity, tcpip

Imagine the following situation:

You have a MySQL server `S` and two clients, `A` and `B`.
Both clients connect to `S` (e.g. using the CLI).

`A` starts a transaction and then locks a table with `WRITE` permissions and inserts a row into the table.

Now `B` tries to select all rows from the table and - of course - has to wait until `A` has committed AND unlocked the table.

Imagine that `A`'s connection is interrupted before it is able to commit or rollback. In my special use-case, the connection might be interrupted at any point in time.

I tested this scenario using three virtual machines which are connected to a common virtual bridge. Using `brctl` I can simply remove individual VMs in order to simulate connection interruptions.

#### The result

Client `B` is stuck, because it waits for the table to get unlocked.
Typing `SHOW PROCESSLIST` in the CLI of the server shows me  this:

```
+----+------+-----------------+----------+---------+------+---------------------------------+----------------------------+----------+
| Id | User | Host            | db       | Command | Time | State                           | Info                       | Progress |
+----+------+-----------------+----------+---------+------+---------------------------------+----------------------------+----------+
|  8 | root | B:38129         | foo      | Query   | 1676 | Waiting for table metadata lock | select blockname from root |    0.000 |
|  9 | root | A:54806         | foo      | Sleep   | 1679 |                                 | NULL                       |    0.000 |
| 12 | root | localhost       | NULL     | Query   |    0 | init                            | show processlist           |    0.000 |
+----+------+-----------------+----------+---------+------+---------------------------------+----------------------------+----------+
```

So the server thinks that the connection from `A` is still alive, while it already was lost *minutes* ago. Having a look at `netstat` also tells me that the connection is still considered to be `ESTABLISHED` and still alive.

I also observed the bridge: Not a single packet from `S` to `A`.

Client `B` is stuck forever. I have to restart the whole server to unlock the table.

#### What I expected

I want my server to detect (after some predefined time) that the connection to `A` is lost even if `A` did not send any more queries. Then I want my server to rollback any uncommitted transactions and finally to unlock the table.

How can I realise this?

Why aren't there any TCP keepalives from `S` to `A`?

Is it possible to define any kind of timeouts?

---

I played around with the variables `wait_timeout`, `innodb_lock_wait_timeout`, and `interactive_timeout`.

- `interactive_timeout` is not interesting because my productive system will not use the CLI.
- `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` seems not to be respected in any way.
- `wait_timeout` indeed improves my situation: idling sessions are killed after the timeout. But I only want them to be killed in case of connection interruption. I want to keep the connection alive to improve performance (save tcp handshakes, SQL logins, db selection...)

Comment: Smells like a bug.  Report it at http://bugs.mysql.com .

Comment: "Locks the table" -- Are you using MyISAM?  Please provide the queries in the transactions and `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the tables.

Answer (score 1):

In your case it shows that the session from client `A` is interrupted but not released on DB because of the MySQL instance has not terminated the connection from client `A` as it feels their is some calculation going on client side. The MySQL instance only stops/terminates the connections once it reaches the threshold time for session staying in IDLE state.

So, this IDLE state time limit is manage by `wait_timeout` parameter. So, you are suppose to set the value for `wait_timeout` parameter to your optimal usage of instance. Many of the cases 180 seconds seems to be ideal.